# Segmentation fault after first call to dprintf() or vdprintf()

Tags: linux, gcc

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 on a Oracle Virtual Box.

I have few calls to **printf()** functions that use file descriptors,
but get segmentation fault after the second call.
I tried **fsync(fd)** and **fdatasync(fd)** but it didn't solve the problem:

```
logFileFd = open("./logFile.log", O_APPEND);

if (logFileFd == -1)
{
    printf("\ncan't create file %s :[%s]", logFileName, strerror(err));
    exit(ERROR_OPEN_LOG_FILE);
}

va_start(a_list, format);
sprintf(logStr, "%s, %s, INFO, %s, %d - ", __DATE__, __TIME__, __BASE_FILE__, __LINE__);
printf("%s", logStr);
dprintf(logFileFd, "%s", logStr);
vprintf(format, a_list);
vdprintf(logFileFd, format, a_list);
va_end(a_list);
close(logFileFd);
```

the segmentation fault occurs at the line:
**vdprintf(logFileFd, format, a_list);**

Can any one assist why is that?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: `dprintf(logFileFd, "%s", logStr);` ? Just `write()` it. Anyway, if you use `fd` as a `FILE`, just `fopen` it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting man page for [vfprintf(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/vfprintf):

> The functions vprintf(), vfprintf(), vsprintf(), vsnprintf() are
> equivalent to the functions printf(), fprintf(), sprintf(),
> snprintf(), respectively, except that they are called with a va_list
> instead of a variable number of arguments. These functions do not call
> the va_end macro. Because they invoke the va_arg macro, the value of
> ap is undefined after the call.

Additionally on the man page for [stdarg(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg) you can read that:

> If ap is passed to a function that uses va_arg(ap,type) then the value
> of ap is undefined after the return of that function.

The problem in your code is that you are using va_list `a_list` twice - first in call to `vprintf()`, then in call to `vdprintf()`. After the first call, `a_list` value is undefined.

Man [stdarg(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg) states that "Multiple traversals of the list, each bracketed by va_start() and va_end() are possible". Try applying following modification:

```c
sprintf(logStr, "%s, %s, INFO, %s, %d - ", __DATE__, __TIME__, __BASE_FILE__, __LINE__);
printf("%s", logStr);
dprintf(logFileFd, "%s", logStr);

va_start(a_list, format);
vprintf(format, a_list);
va_end(a_list);

va_start(a_list, format);
vdprintf(logFileFd, format, a_list);
va_end(a_list);
```

Additionally, please review the flags used in call to `open()`. According to man page [open(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

> The argument flags must include one of the following access
> modes: O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, or O_RDWR

I would propose to apply following modification:

```c
logFileFd = open("./logFile.log", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you (ytta) very very much for your prompted help.

I implemented all your answer and suggestions and it worked perfectly.

The only thing I needed to add (which was not in my question) is the **mode_t** to the **open()** function and use the it as:
**int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);**
setting **mode** to **0777**
because when I added the O_CREAT bit: **open("./logFile.log", O_APPEND | OCREAT);**
the file **logFile.log** was created with the **sticky** bit ON (enabled) in the file system, and in the next iteration the **open()** failed.

Thanks again very much for your help.

Comment: Glad to help. If my answer resolved your issue, feel free to mark it as [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) :)